# Search Methods For Showing Results Similar to Item Entered

Tags: php, mysql, search, catalog

I am building a data driven website (using PHP and MySQL) for some farmers around the community (well, was - you will see in a second). They wanted to be able to list their products and have people search those products and their names come up along with a link to a page detailing all of their produce.

While I knew it would be a long list, I thought, "Since every search into a mysql database is picky - including case sensitive - I'll just make a list in alphabetical order and people can choose from a dropdown box what they want to search for. No problem."

Well, now it's a problem. He has expanded the parameters of the site. He now wants to included hand made and home made products. Needless to say we went from a few dozen to hundreds of potential products and now a dropdown list is no longer feasible. But if I use a text field for visitors to search the site, unless they type it with no spelling errors and use the same case, they won't get accurate results from the search.

Can anyone recommend another method? I am aware of the "LIKE" search, but it doesn't really solve my problem - especially since it could create false positives in the search. Any help would be appreciated, thanks!

Comment: How about a 'type ahead' sort of search? You could also have synonyms stored so 'handmade' and 'homemade' would be found together.

Comment: Forgive my ignorance, I am self-taught and somewhat new, but I just thought of something. Are there case insensitive collations in MySQL that combined with the LIKE search would greatly broaden the results?

Answer (score 0):

Well, the question is somewhat vague, since you are talking about multiple search parameters.

It's more a design choice. For example, consider the following:

- For items such as "homemade" or "handmade", perhaps underneath the input field, you should have a checkbox where people can add additional flags to the search
- say, search by name "John Smith" and check off "handmade" and "homemade"
- The "handmade" and "homemade" fields in the database will always be the same (either on / off)

So, an sql query might be like this:

```
SELECT * FROM products WHERE farmername LIKE '%$search%' AND handmade = 'handmade'
```

Or, when inputting the data, if handmade is checked, insert an integer into the handmade, where 1 would mean handmade was checked, 0 handmade was not checked

so your query would then go AND handmade = 1 (or 0) for not handmade

These are just some ideas to get you going, but this is more a design decision than a database decision, how do you create your tables to use the flags

Answer (score 0):

I would use two tables:

- one with all possible search terms
- one with synonyms of any terms that were applicable (EG "handmade" and "homemade" )

Use AJAX to search for values from the first table as characters are entered in a text box. Return a list of possible terms using:

> select term from search_table where term like '%<input string>%'

Only start returning values when you have less than 10 hits or so. (IE don't populate when they enter 2 letters ). Then when a particular term is entered, search in the second table for synonyms and include those with the search. In the results page, indicate that you included the synonyms and maybe put an 'X' by each to opt to re-search with those excluded.

Note that 'like' is case-insensitive.